# How to uninstall Jenkins on mac completely

Tags: macos, jenkins, homebrew

I installed Jenkins with brew on mac. But it occurs some problem, I want to re-install it. Previously, at the first time I access http://localhost:8080, the page guides you to install some plugins and need you to input the password. But when I use 'brew uninstall jenkins' command and install again, the page will not show. I don't remember the previous default admin passsword. So I can't access the jenkins now. I delete the homebrew cache as well, it not worked.
Is there any solutions to uninstall Jenkins completely? I just want to start from the beginning of the installation.
Thanks.

Comment: Try adding `--force` when removing.

Comment: Thanks,I tried, but it didn't work

Answer (score 51):

In terminal, write and execute

```
$/Library/Application\ Support/Jenkins/Uninstall.command
```

**Note** If you installed it with **sudo**, then use this:

```
$sudo /Library/Application\ Support/Jenkins/Uninstall.command
```

Then follow the instructions.

Comment: I installed the latest Jenkins version 2.80.
And i can't find the uninstall.command file.

Comment: Worked on Jenkins 2.82, but I installed it via a.pkg file

Comment: can add that it worked like a charm with 2.73.1 LTS. had to navigate to the folder manually though. plus you need sudo (admin) password

Answer (score 17):

Remove the hidden `.jenkins` directory in your home directory that contains the configuration.

Comment: You should explain your answer

Comment: I think the `$HOME/.jenkins` directory typically only applies to Homebrew users, like @jaju mentioned in their pseudo-comment/answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50960001/2291928). But this is indeed where Jenkins content lives for `brew` users, not in `/Library/Application Support/Jenkins` or anywhere like that.

Comment: FYI, I did not install via Brew and had a .jenkins folder.  Thanks for this tip from me.

Answer (score 6):

Removing the .jenkins file is actually *an* answer, depending how Jenkins was installed. For example, the homebrew installation does create instance-specific work area in $HOME/.jenkins

If you have the jenkins instance already running, go to $JENKINS_BASE_URL/configure and check the value of '*Home directory*' - that is the place where all user-specific data is stored, like the jobs.

PS: BTW - can't get away from SO stupidity. This is a comment to the answer by Ayobi, but don't have reputation to comment.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

1. `brew uninstall jenkins-lts`
2. `rm -r /Users/admin/.jenkins`

Answer (score 3):

To uninstall Jenkins service from your Mac OS X computer, execute uninstall script from terminal:

```
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
/Library/Application Support/Jenkins/Uninstall.command
```

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Thanks+for+using+OSX+Installer

Answer (score 3):

I installed Jenkins as `pkg` from jenkins.io. There was some issue and I wanted to delete it. I couldn't find Jenkins folder or Uninstall Command in `Library`, so this is what I did,

1. Go to `/Applications` --> Delete the Jenkins folder
2. Delete `/Users/Shared/Jenkins`
3. Delete Jenkins (*there will be a `standard` user with `no name` username for the first time when jenkins is installed*) from "Users & Groups"

After this I re-installed Jenkins and it seem to work.

Comment: I'm not able to select that unnamed standard user. How do i delete it?

Comment: @Krutika Sonawala  I know its silly to ask but did you unlock the User's & Group settings, so that it is editable? I was able to delete without any issue